# Resize image before saving to Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

What's typically the process to resize an image before saving it to Core Data?

I would like to be able to resize an image to 75px75p before saving it to Core Data to minimize its size. The image can come directly from the Photos library or the camera. I have a feeling that the way I'm currently saving it, it's saving a huge file size where in reality I only need a thumbnail image (75x75).

Here is how I'm currently saving it.

**Core Data Object:** `Item`

**Attribute:** `image: Binary Data`

```
// image is passed to the addItem function directly from an Image Picker
func addItem(name:String, image:UIImage?){
    if let image = image {
        imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)!
    }else{
        imageData = nil
    }
    item.name = name
    item.image = imageData
    self.manager.save()
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not scale the image just before converting it to JPEG data? And I suggest change the JPEG quality to 1.0 for the tiny image unless you really want a blurry image.

Comment: I changed it to 0.1 thinking it would reduce its size. What scaling method do you recommend? Thank you for the advice.

Comment: The lower JPEG quality will result in the data being fewer bytes but the image size (points/pixels) doesn't change.

Comment: Ah good to know, I now just need to find a method to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is scale the image before getting the JPEG data.

```swift
func addItem(name: String, image: UIImage?) {
    let size = CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)
    var imageData: Data? = nil
    if let thumb = image?.preparingThumbnail(of: size) {
        imageData = thumb.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
    }

    item.name = name
    item.image = imageData
    self.manager.save()
}
```

Note that `preparingThumbnail(of:)` does requires iOS 15.0 or later.

Comment: Just to be clear, changing the size of the image with `CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)` does in fact change the actual size (points/pixels) of the image, right?

Comment: @fs_tigre Using `preparingThumbnail(of:)` returns a new image with the requested size. The original image is not affected. See the documentation for `preparingThumbnail(of;)`.

Comment: Ah ok, got it. thanks a lot for the clarification.